# Datastage Scenario Based Requirement

Tags: datastage

Requirement

**i/p**

abc  1 1234  null

abc  1 null  4561

**o/p**

abc 1 1234 4561

How to do it using Datastage?

Comment: In general sample data is a good start but please provide also your business requirement. I.e. for your case if there alre always two and only two rows - column names would be good to refer to the name etc. Do not let us guess.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the very basic information from your query I suggest trying an Aggregator stage but it could also be solved with a transformer.

The first two columns seem to be the key columns and use max for all the other ones in the aggregator.